# Post to friends wall

Tags: php, facebook, api, token

I have this code that post a message on the friend's wall, but when i use it i receive this error:{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}};

What i can do to solve this problem?

Someone can help me? Thanks

This is my code:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';


$app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
));


$session = $facebook->getUser();


$me = null;
if ($session) {
try {
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
}
}

if ($me) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>Send Message</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
session : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>,
status : true, 
cookie : true, 
xfbml : true 
});


FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
window.location.reload();
});
};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>

<?php if ($me){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">
<img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">
</a>
<?php }else { ?>
<div>
<fb:login-button perms="publish_stream,offline_access"></fb:login-button>
<?php }
if ($me)
{
    $atoken=$facebook->getAccessToken();

$friends = $facebook->api('me/friends');
$message="This is a Test!";
for($i=0;$i<count($friends['data']);$i++)
{
$url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$friends['data'][$i]['id']."/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"access_token=".$atoken."&message=".$message);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try inspecting the HTTP request that gets made to facebook to grab the token. You can do this using the network tab in chrome inspector or firebug. Make sure the data being passed in the request body is correct. If everything is correct then start stepping through your code by adding die() statements so you can print out data to see what is happening along the way, i.e. `die(var_dump($session));`

Answer (score 0):

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/: you need to ask the user to re-authorize your app. The page says:

```
OAuth   190     C unless a subcode is present   Most OAuth errors include a subcode. Use the subcode table to determine the correct recovery tactic.
```

The option C says:

```
Authorize/reauthorize the user
Example: an expired token requires reauthorization of the application by the user
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to post on to a friend's wall has been removed or depreciated since past few months by Facebook, the same documented in this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/). Also, if you still want to allow User's to post to friend's wall, the blog post suggests

> If you want to allow people to post to their friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). Stories that include friends via [user mentions tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/) or [action tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople/) will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag).